# Outgoing calls not recording

Tags: android, android-service, telephonymanager, android-mediarecorder, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying add one thing in my app. What i am trying is whenever user get phone call or user make phone call, at same time recording should be start and recording must store in sd card after cutting the call.

**Issues**
1)Incoming call record work sometimes

2)Outgoing not working

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
    private ComponentName mAdminName;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        try {
            // Initiate DevicePolicyManager.
            mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminDemo.class);

            if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Click on Activate button to secure your application.");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                // mDPM.lockNow();
                // Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                // TrackDeviceService.class);
                // startService(intent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

TService

```
public class TService extends Service {
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    File audiofile;
    String name, phonenumber;
    String audio_format;
    public String Audio_Type;
    int audioSource;
    Context context;

    Timer timer;
    Boolean offHook = false, ringing = false;
    Toast toast;
    Boolean isOffHook = false;
    private boolean recordstarted = false;

    private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
    private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
    private CallBr br_call;




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("service", "destroy");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // final String terminate =(String)
        // intent.getExtras().get("terminate");//
        // intent.getStringExtra("terminate");
        // Log.d("TAG", "service started");
        //
        // TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
        // getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); // TelephonyManager
        // // object
        // CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new
        // CustomPhoneStateListener();
        // telephony.listen(customPhoneListener,
        // PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        // context = getApplicationContext();

        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
        this.br_call = new CallBr();
        this.registerReceiver(this.br_call, filter);

        // if(terminate != null) {
        // stopSelf();
        // }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Bundle bundle;
        String state;
        String inCall, outCall;
        public boolean wasRinging = false;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        wasRinging = true;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                        if (wasRinging == true) {

                            Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                            File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/TestRecordingDasa1");
                            if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                                sampleDir.mkdirs();
                            }
                            String file_name = "Record";
                            try {
                                audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                            System.out.println("PATH"+path);

                            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
//                          recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);

                            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
                            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                            try {
                                recorder.prepare();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            recorder.start();
                            recordstarted = true;
                        }
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        wasRinging = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (recordstarted) {
                            recorder.stop();
                            recordstarted = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove  this  `if (wasRinging == true)` from TService, this wasRining Boolean checks if the phone was ringing some time before, i.e. when phone receives a call, in case of outgoing call it stays false so, the recorder part is skipped. Just change that and it should work.

Just replace your TService code with this..

```
    public class TService extends Service {
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    File audiofile;
    String name, phonenumber;
    String audio_format;
    public String Audio_Type;
    int audioSource;
    Context context;

    Timer timer;
    Boolean offHook = false, ringing = false;
    Toast toast;
    Boolean isOffHook = false;
    private boolean recordstarted = false;

    private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
    private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
    private CallBr br_call;




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("service", "destroy");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // final String terminate =(String)
        // intent.getExtras().get("terminate");//
        // intent.getStringExtra("terminate");
        // Log.d("TAG", "service started");
        //
        // TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
        // getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); // TelephonyManager
        // // object
        // CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new
        // CustomPhoneStateListener();
        // telephony.listen(customPhoneListener,
        // PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        // context = getApplicationContext();

        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
        this.br_call = new CallBr();
        this.registerReceiver(this.br_call, filter);

        // if(terminate != null) {
        // stopSelf();
        // }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Bundle bundle;
        String state;
        String inCall, outCall;
        public boolean wasRinging = false;
        public boolean didMakeACall = false;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        wasRinging = true;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                        if (wasRinging || didMakeACall) {

                            Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                            File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/TestRecordingDasa1");
                            if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                                sampleDir.mkdirs();
                            }
                            String file_name = "Record";
                            try {
                                audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                            System.out.println("PATH"+path);

                            recorder = new MediaRecorder();


                            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
                            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                            try {
                                recorder.prepare();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            recorder.start();
                            recordstarted = true;
                        }
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        wasRinging = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (recordstarted) {
                            recorder.stop();
                            recordstarted = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    didMakeACall = true;
                    outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i dint get what you say..sorry for english

Comment: I've editted my answer, just replace your TService code with mine.

Comment: yes! i have, on kitkat its working fine, i haven't tested on newer versions though.

Comment: i have kitkat too..i am not getting toast even.. and incoming outgoing nothing works..can you upload demo?

Comment: folder is not creating also..can you help?

Comment: okay sure i can.. but i do not have access to a computer right now, I will for sure in couple of hours.

Comment: I will make a github project and let you know.

Comment: Here..  https://github.com/ashiwalia/AutomaticCallRecorder1  Please note this might not work in all devices because some manufactures disable call recording because some countries don't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid community wouldn't like external links here so I'm posting my quick demo project here...

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".TService"/>
</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

I'm starting TService in its onCreate method, please note that this could be any activity in your project,  or any context you can start a service from.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this, TService.class));
    }
}
```

and now finally,
**TService.java**
I've tested this in Kitkat and Lollipop and it's working, for newer versions you need to explicitly ask for Manifest permissions during run time and it should work just as fine.

```
public class TService extends Service {
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    File audiofile;
    String name, phonenumber;
    String audio_format;
    public String Audio_Type;
    int audioSource;
    Context context;

    Timer timer;
    Boolean offHook = false, ringing = false;
    Toast toast;
    Boolean isOffHook = false;
    private boolean recordstarted = false;

    private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
    private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
    private CallBr br_call;




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("service", "destroy");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // final String terminate =(String)
        // intent.getExtras().get("terminate");//
        // intent.getStringExtra("terminate");
        // Log.d("TAG", "service started");
        //
        // TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
        // getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); // TelephonyManager
        // // object
        // CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new
        // CustomPhoneStateListener();
        // telephony.listen(customPhoneListener,
        // PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        // context = getApplicationContext();

        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
        this.br_call = new CallBr();
        this.registerReceiver(this.br_call, filter);

        // if(terminate != null) {
        // stopSelf();
        // }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Bundle bundle;
        String state;
        String inCall, outCall;
        public boolean wasRinging = false;
        boolean didMakeACall = false;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        wasRinging = true;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                        if (wasRinging || didMakeACall) {

                            Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                            File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/MyRecorder");
                            if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                                sampleDir.mkdirs();
                            }
                            String file_name = "Record";
                            try {
                                audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                            System.out.println("PATH"+path);

                            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
//                          recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);

                            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
                            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                            try {
                                recorder.prepare();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            recorder.start();
                            recordstarted = true;
                        }
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        wasRinging = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (recordstarted) {
                            recorder.stop();
                            recordstarted = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    didMakeACall = true;
                    outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: which device you used?

Comment: htc desire 820g runing kitkat and emulator running lollipop, if you're having problems I can make a github project and share with you

Comment: i am using emulator kitkat..google nexus 7 api level 4.4.4. in this its not working

Comment: If i remember correctly Nexus 7 didn't have cellular connectivity so, how are you even making calls? Try to use some other emulator, I'm sure it will work.